# Chrome, after hours of no issues - net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR, then ajax interval stops working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a php page that plays short videos looping for hours.  I also do an ajax call every 60 seconds to log the watch time.  After several hours and several hundred ajax pings working fine, I randomly get the these errors:
Chrome: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR, pointing to nothing
-or-
Opera:  GET 'some long url pointing to the video host file' NET::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET 200
-or-
Chrome also: net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR and pointing to my ajax js

In all cases, the ajax ping stops working but other ajax pings are still working and the video keeps playing.  I have 2-3 of them that run at intervals doing other logging.  None are set to less than 60 seconds.

I've been researching this for days and I can't seem to nail down what is causing this. It seems that there's something somewhere resetting the connection?  Could it be my router, the ISP, the browsers, the host? (they claim it's not them).  Is this caused by the repeated ajax calls?  Perhaps some ddos-attack prevention suddenly activating?

The video playback embed is supplied by the video host and is set to loop.

Here is the ajax update logging code:

```js
// Javascript:

    // updates log time
    function updateVidTime()
        {
            url = current_url;

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    'updateTime': 1,
                    'videoID': videoID,
                    'visitID': visitID,
                    'current_url': current_url,
                    'timeSec': timeSec,
                },


                success: function(data)
                    {
                        var response = JSON.parse(data);
                        timeSec = parseInt(response.timeSec) + waitTime;
                        timerStarted = 0; // after the ajax call, sets it back to 0

                        runVidTimer(); // call the func below that calls the timer again after waiting with settimeout

                    },
                    
            // ajax, end
            });
                
        }

    function runVidTimer() // waits the delayed amt of time, then runs the updateVidTime func
        {
                    // run the timer
                        timerSetTmOut = setTimeout(updateVidTime,timeSecMS);
        }
```

```php
// Php
    if (isset($_POST['updateTime']))
        {
            $videoID = $_POST['videoID'];
            $visitID = $_POST['visitID'];
            $current_url = $_POST['current_url'];
            $timeSec = $_POST['timeSec'];

            
            $sql = "UPDATE log SET timeSec = '{$timeSec}' WHERE visitID = '{$visitID}' AND page = '{$current_url}'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                    
                    if ($result)
                        {
                            $response = array
                                (
                                    'timeSec' => $timeSec
                                );
                            echo json_encode($response);
                            exit();
                        }

        }
```

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the right side? If multiple browsers fail in the same way, are you sure it's not your PHP that stopped working? Which you might find out by making sure you maintain an activity log for PHP so you can see whether it stops writing to that log, and if so, with log entries that let you gain insight into what was happening before it got stuck.

Comment: FYI: Your PHP is wide open to SQL injection - always use a `prepared statement` when using user supplied ( or modifiable ) data in any sort of SQL query, **never** embed variables like this directly in the sql.

Comment: @MikePomaxKamermans thanks so much for the insight.  I host on fastcomet so am not sure how to check the php log.  I do read the error_log in the site root but it's pretty much blank unless I get an immediate error.  I've love to log this page to the nth degree to track this down.  Any suggestions on how to log these?  I did run chrome://net-export/ and generated a 2GB json file that I can't even load in the viewer.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius appreciate you pointing that out.  I do need to go through all my ajax calls and secure them up - I'm not too familiar with PDO if that's the reference.  For now, just trying to solve this error.

Comment: Either `PDO` or `mysqli` offer the ability to use `prepared statements` which api you choose is personal preference. Generally I think PDO is more refined and flexible. As for the above it is unclear what numbers of visitors are hitting your app - are there hundreds of simultaneous users or is this just for you in testing? You might look at server-sent events as an alternative to ajax ~ one connection per client for as long as required with updates done to the db periodically within an infinite loop

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius thanks very much.  started reading about prepared and it's within my scope of understanding.  as for the issue at hand, this is just me testing the video site.  my regular ajax calls are sending video watch time back to the server and retrieving other data like showing active users.  any thoughts on how i could track down what is causing the error?